# Does altimeter setting affect the vertical guidance in a LPV approach?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures, gnss, ifr-navigation

I had assumed during a WAAS approach when the GPS is in LPV mode, both lateral guidance and vertical guidance are generated from GPS/WAAS signals and the pitot-static system should have no effect on its vertical guidance. This is in contrast with LNAV/VNAV approach, where the vertical guidance comes from the barometric system, the same source as altimeter.

However, when I read [RNAV (GPS) Z RWY 30 @ KHAF](http://flightaware.com/resources/airport/KHAF/IAP/RNAV+(GPS)+Z+RWY+30), I will get a different DA if I use a different altimeter setting. So, why does altimeter settings matter to the DA in an LPV approach?

[image]

Comment: To directly answer your question, "...why does altimeter settings matter to the DA in an LPV approach?", it is because the DA is still predicated on the barometric altitude.

Comment: @Porcupine911: It make sense. The minimum (DA in this example) given in the approach plate is baro-minimum, as against radar-altimeter minimum or GPS-altitude minimum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Short Answer:

No, the vertical component of LPV approach performance is based on WAAS GPS input, not the altimeter or barometric system.

### Longer Answer:

Your assumption about LPV performance is correct: Baro-VNAV is not used for LPV approaches.

On any type of approach with a [Decision Altitude (DA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_approach#Decision_height_or_altitude), the aircraft's arrival at the DA is determined by the pilot's reading of the aircraft's [sensitive altimeter](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/16916/12720).

If the altimeter is set to an altimeter setting report from a distant reporting station, SFO in this case, then the DA may be increased to give additional altitude margin to allow for variance in local atmospheric pressure.

This is true for the DA or [Minimum Descent Altitude (MDA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_approach#Minimum_descent_altitude_.28MDA.29) on any approach, whether a GPS approach or not. See the [MKT ILS 33](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1602/pdf/05755IL33.PDF) and [MKT RNAV 15](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1602/pdf/05755R15.PDF) for other examples of this. See the following excerpts from the [Aeronautical Information Manual](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim_basic_4-03-14.pdf) on altimeter settings for approaches (emphasis mine):

> **5-4-5**
>   **a.**
>   **4.** Approach minimums are based on the local
>   altimeter setting for that airport, unless annotated
>   otherwise; e.g., Oklahoma City/Will Rogers World
>   approaches are based on having a Will Rogers World
>   altimeter setting. When a different altimeter source is
>   required, or more than one source is authorized, it will
>   be annotated on the approach chart; e.g., use Sidney
>   altimeter setting, if not received, use Scottsbluff
>   altimeter setting. ***Approach minimums may be raised
>   when a nonlocal altimeter source is authorized.*** When
>   more than one altimeter source is authorized, and the
>   minima are different, they will be shown by separate
>   lines in the approach minima box or a note; e.g., use
>   Manhattan altimeter setting; when not available use
>   Salina altimeter setting and increase all MDAs
>   40 feet. When the altimeter must be obtained from a
>   source other than air traffic a note will indicate the
>   source; e.g., Obtain local altimeter setting on CTAF.
>   When the altimeter setting(s) on which the approach
>   is based is not available, the approach is not
>   authorized. Baro−VNAV must be flown using the
>   local altimeter setting only. Where no local altimeter
>   is available, the LNAV/VNAV line will still be
>   published for use by WAAS receivers with a note that
>   Baro−VNAV is not authorized. When a local and at
>   least one other altimeter setting source is authorized
>   and the local altimeter is not available Baro−VNAV
>   is not authorized; however, the LNAV/VNAV
>   minima can still be used by WAAS receivers using the
>   alternate altimeter setting source.

Note that Baro-VNAV is a type of VNAV system which uses barometric
altimetry as a basis for vertical navigation performance. An LNAV/VNAV approach can be flown using WAAS equipment without a Baro-VNAV system.

Comment: So what you're saying is that, although *vertical guidance* is being provided by WAAS the DA is set by baro altimeter?

Comment: @TomMcW The [DA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_approach#Decision_height_or_altitude) is the altitude at which the pilot decides whether to continue with the approach or go missed; the pilot determines arrival at this altitude by reference to the aircraft altimeter. Baro-VNAV is a vertical navigational system to which gives the required navigational performance for the VNAV component of LNAV/VNAV approaches (though other systems such as WAAS can also provide this level of performance). Does that answer your question? I wasn't quite certain what you meant by `baro altimeter`.

Comment: I guess what I'm summarizing from your answer is that the although the WAAS guidance is not affected by the altimeter setting the FAA still sets the DA by the pressure altimeter and not the altitude calculated by the GPS. Is that correct?

Comment: @TomMcW That's correct. You probably already understand this, but in an attempt to be perfectly clear, let me reiterate that pilots rely on the indicated altitude as seen on the sensitive altimeter, not the altitude given by the GPS (which may be the true altitude, depending on the GPS precision).

Comment: Why is that? Doesn't WAAS GPS give you a more accurate and reliable attitude that is not dependant on QNH?

Comment: @TomMcW Yes, WAAS altitude is very precise and reliable. That's a good question—probably a good new question on it's own! The answer is long and includes the recent development of precise GPS and the usefulness of having all aircraft with altimeters set the same. It's simpler.

Comment: I figure it's so everybody is on the same page as far as altitude is concerned concerning separation. Same reason everybody uses 29.92 above TA. It just seems for approach and landing purposes, though, you'd want to use whatever is most accurate so you don't bump into terrain.

Comment: This answer is dead on. If the missed approach point was a specified distance from the runway instead of a specified altitude, then the altimeter setting wouldn't matter because all guidance would be generated by the GPS signal.  Since you are referring to the altimeter to determine when to go missed though, you could possibly continue following the GPS signal to an altitude lower than intended if the altimeter is not set to the correct altitude for the field.  Maybe that will help to understand why it matters though if you determine the missed approach point by the altitude instead.