# Are ERA5 Pressure Level and ADS-B Geometric Height comparable?

Tags: altitude, ads-b

I have two wind data sets that I want to compare:

- a) Aircraft derived data (ADS-B and Mode-S).
- b) ERA5 Reanalysis data.
  To compare both I need altitudes to be comparable. On data set a) I have the **geometric height**. Precisely, it corresponds to **Data Item from I021/140** from ICAO document Part 12: Category 021, as seen in the following image:

[image]

On the other hand, data set b) is given in "**pressure levels**". What I did is to transform this pressure level on b) to altitude using the ISA model. Then I supposed I can compare this altitude with the geometric height given on a). But I am not sure if it's correct to do so. I don't know if the pressure level on ERA5 is just a way to indicate altitudes or not.

Is it correct? If not, is there any way to compare them?

Doc.:

- ERA5 reanalysis data ([click here](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-pressure-levels?tab=form))
- ERA5 model levels definition ([click here](https://www.ecmwf.int/en/forecasts/documentation-and-support/137-model-levels))
- ERA5 geometric height and pressure level ([click here](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/CKB/ERA5%3A+compute+pressure+and+geopotential+on+model+levels%2C+geopotential+height+and+geometric+height)).
- ERA5 Doc ([click here](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/CKB/ERA5%3A+data+documentation#ERA5:datadocumentation-Introduction) and [here](https://www.ecmwf.int/en/elibrary/16648-ifs-documentation-cy41r2-part-iv-physical-processes) )

Comment: Related [What is the geoid undulation used for in aviation?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44034/3201) I think you need to add the geoid undulation N to the altitude obtained from the ISA model, to get the ellipsoidal height comparable with ADS-B data. Still you'll be comparing a barometric altitude (not an actual altitude) with a GPS altitude.