# What type of altimeter is this?

Tags: military, flight-instruments, altimeter

What type Altimeter is an SA-91? It has three pointers 100, 1000, 10000.
Don't know if it is Kollsman. I can't find any info as far as repairing unit.[image]

Comment: Are you asking who the manufacturer is, or its principle of operation? I'm guessing you want to know who makes it? What aircraft is this from?

Comment: are there any markings on the back? A picture of the back might be helpful.

Comment: It does appear to be a sensitive altimeter with a kollsman type adjustment, though the kollsman window is blacked out—perhaps the adjustment knob has been turned down too far. In other ways it does appear to be a Kollsman *brand* altimeter, markings, shape, and milling. Kollsman brand often had the name stamped into the metal at the back of the instrument as well as a tag, also on the back. Additional photos would be very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

It seems to be a C-12 or C-13 [sensitive](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16910/what-is-the-difference-between-sensitive-and-non-sensitive-altimeters) altimeter (*SA*) from Kollsman Instrument Division / Square D Company, manufactured circa 1940:

[image]
<sup>([Source](https://www.liveauctioneers.com/item/1453586_vint-kollsman-instrumentsquare-d-co-altimeter))</sup>

The only difference seems to be the marking "ALTITUDE" replaced by "SA-91". As this is the 39th in the series, this could be the initial marking, later replaced by the more standard one. I don't see what could be "91" for.

The Kollsman window is black (as commented) because the setting dial has been turned past maximum pressure reference, as indicated by the bug between 7 and 8. The window value and this bug are linked.

The brown color seem to be related to [phosphorescent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorescence) markings and needles.

The C-12 has apparently many variants, likely designed on demand, especially for the USAF, like this one with alternate colors for the marks:

[image]
<sup>C-12 manufactured by *C.G. Conn Ltd.*, ([source](https://www.etsy.com/listing/180016687/c-g-conn-c-12-sensitive-altimeter-flight?utm_source=Pinterest&utm_medium=PageTools&utm_campaign=Share))</sup>

[C.G. Conn Ltd.](https://www.tumblr.com/search/c.g.%20conn) is a music instruments company (saxophones), but at war time they provided aircraft instruments to the USAF ([flying on instruments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn2Yc.gif) finally explained!).

Kollsman published handbooks about their instruments. Here is one from 1938. It doesn't cover this model of altimeter, but can be helpful though:

[image]
<sup>([Source](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015011832311;view=2up;seq=1))</sup>

Comment: Someone just gave me a Kollsman C-12 with the alternating white/blue number markings that looks almost identical to the C. G. Conn you linked to, but mine is manufactured by Square D Company and "KOLLSMAN" is embossed on the back. Per the deatails on a spec place screwed to the back, it's a Type C-12, MFRS Part NO 671 BK-010, CONTR NO AF-33186 and SER NO (serial) 43[unreadable]. My co-worker gave it to me, and supposedly his dad's friend, who was a WWII pilot (deceased) gave it to him. I'd love to know what AC it came out of. Do you know which AC used the White/Blue variant like that?

Comment: FWIW I thought I could look up the coworker's dad's friend and assume it came out of an AC he flew in the war, but unfortunately his last name, "Young" is a terrible search term. Also the first name "Larry" isn't getting me anywhere, either, but it may be short for Lawrence. (It also may be a middle name..)

Comment: @elrobis: 43 is the year of manufacturing. From [here](https://aeroantique.com/products/altimeter-sensitive-type-c-12-50-000-ft-us-army-air-force-wwii-2?variant=18570344824921): "*The C-12 Altimeter was used across all aircraft of the Air Corps US Army, including heavy bombers B-17 and B-24, medium bombers, B-25 and B-26, Fighters P-38, P-39, P-40, P-47, and P-51, and transports C-46 and C-47, according to the Maintenance Interchangeability Chart dated Dec 1943.*"

Answer (score 3):

The altimeter was used in a Nuclear Weapon test set neither a CAT or FAT test set. It was used to test the BARO switches in the weapon. The "SA" printed on the dial was for Sandia Apparatus

Comment: To me this is very plausible, [Sandia (SNL) was in charge](https://cryptome.org/nuke-fuze.htm) of the [baro fuse](https://www.flickr.com/photos/rocbolt/47462119101) to replace the radar fuse and the phrase [Sandia apparatus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEIqD.png) has been used for commercially available instruments with additional Sandia-provided requirements. Can you provide some reference?

Answer (score 1):

Of interest is the serial number on the face of the instrument.  Yes it appears to be the Kollsman type but lacks the barometric readout in the "Kollsman window".

I suspect that you have an early prototype of the Kollsman.  At least that is my best guess.  I'm not an expert on antique altimeters but just a knowledgeable pilot and aviation enthusiast.